# prstat on solaris - can you make it flash when size exceeds a limit?

Tags: solaris

I have been told to make prstat flash the background from white to black a few times when any value in the size category passes a threshold. Is there a way to edit the command and put this in here or will this never happen?

Comment: The source code to prstat was published in OpenSolaris, so you could take those sources and modify them, but they'll be newer than what's in Solaris 10, and older than what's in Solaris 11, so not a good match for either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be mean, but somebody who asked for this is not being reasonable or does not understand.  I would guess the "asker" has no clue about prstat. Look at these two examples:

```
example% prstat -u root -n 5 -P 1,2 1 1

PID   USERNAME  SWAP   RSS STATE  PRI  NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/LWP
 306   root     3024K 1448K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.3% sendmail/1
 102   root     1600K  592K sleep   59    0   0:00.00 0.1% in.rdisc/1
 250   root     1000K  552K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% utmpd/1
 288   root     1720K 1032K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% sac/1
   1   root      744K  168K sleep   58    0   0:00.00 0.0% init/1
TOTAL:       25, load averages:  0.05, 0.08, 0.12


example% prstat -S rss -n 5 -vc -u root,john

 PID USERNAME USR SYS TRP TFL DFL LCK SLP LAT VCX ICX SCL SIG PROCESS/LWP
   1 root     0.0 0.0  -   -   -   -  100  -    0   0   0   0 init/1
 102 root     0.0 0.0  -   -   -   -  100  -    0   0   3   0 in.rdisc/1
 250 root     0.0 0.0  -   -   -   -  100  -    0   0   0   0 utmpd/1
1185 john    0.0 0.0  -   -   -   -  100  -    0   0   0   0 csh/1
 240 root     0.0 0.0  -   -   -   -  100  -    0   0   0   0 powerd/4
 TOTAL:       71, load averages:  0.02, 0.04, 0.08
```

So, what value do you look for?  There are lots of things prstat displays, so you have to learn all of them then code for whatever each of the many possible outputs means.

To do this:

What you will have to do is to run prstat with arguments entered on the command line, in a child process, read and interpret everything it produces, then map it to output and flash the screen as appropriate.  You can do this with coprocesses in ksh or zsh  or by using fifos in bash.  Consider running prtstat in -e mode regardless of the what the user enters so you have full screens to read and manipulate.

Flashing the screen can be done with escape sequences, like changing background color or whatever you want.  Here is a starting point for Windows based terminals:

[ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

And for Vt100 (UNIX)

[terminal escape codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)